# Deleted GAL in EMC and ADSIEDIT now Error

Tags: active-directory, exchange, powershell, exchange-2013

I attempted to delete a Global Address List via Exchange Management Console and ADSIEDIT as I made a typo during the creation.

Now when I try to create a new GAL, i get the following error

> [PS] C:\Windows\system32>New-GlobalAddressList -Name "Tenant00001 - GAL" -ConditionalCustomAttribute1 "Tenant00001" -Inc
>   ludedRecipients MailboxUsers -RecipientContainer "********dc.com/HostedExchange"
>
> WARNING: One or more global address lists were missing from the Active Directory attribute.  This is likely caused by
>   using legacy Exchange management tools to create global address lists.
>   An Active Directory Constraint Violation error occurred on ***MasterDC.*******dc.com. Additional information: The
>   name reference is invalid.
>   This may be caused by replication latency between Active Directory domain controllers.
>   Active directory response: 000020B5: AtrErr: DSID-0315286E, #1:
>       0: 000020B5: DSID-0315286E, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 907ff (globalAddressList2)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-GlobalAddressList], ADConstraintViolationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=C********R01,RequestId=e066151b-e695-494e-b238-f1b0f141c708,TimeStamp=15/12/20
>      14 17:21:56] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ADConstraintViolationException] 62CA54FF,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.System
>     ConfigurationTasks.NewGlobalAddressList
>       + PSComputerName        : **asvr01.*******dc.com
>
> [PS] C:\Windows\system32>

In ADSIEDIT I deleted (right click > delete) the specific GAL in config > Services > MS Exch > Address List Container > All Global Address Lists.

The get-gloabaladdresslist powershell cmdlet confirms that the GAL is deleted.

DC is running 2008R2
Domain functional level is also 2008 R2
Exchange is 2013

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by going to the following location in ADSIEDIT

Domain > Configuration > Services

Right Click CN=Microsoft Exchange > Properties

Found and Removed a bad entry from the GlobalAddressList1 attribute.

Comment: Cool! Mark your answer correct by clicking the checkmark outline on the left